# HTML5 Touchmove event only in one direction

Tags: html, drag, direction, touches

Im creating an object to drag with "touchmove" in Y but i want it only to be dragged in one direction, up!

But it also makes it go down.. How can i solve this?

In each interval of Y some actions will take place there and the objective is to drag the item only in one way disabling the possibility to the user dont go to the previews actions.

Here is the code:

```
    var moveMe = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var orig = e.originalEvent;
    var y = event.touches[0].pageY;
    if(y<=600 && y>420){
        $(this).css({
            top: orig.changedTouches[0].pageY
        });
        if(y<570 && y>=540){

        }else {
            if(y<540 && y>=510){

            }else {
                if(y<510 && y>=480){

                }else {
                    if(y<480 && y>=450){

                    }else {
                        if(y<450 && y>=420){

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

};

$("#draggable").bind("touchstart touchmove", moveMe);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but is it possible that you have a mistake in the following line?

```
var y = event.touches[0].pageY;
```

shoudn't you use here "e" instead of "event"?

hope it helps.